# Why is it not possible to import a single function from File::Spec?

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
use File::Spec qw(catfile);
use File::Copy qw(copy);

catfile("a","b");
copy("a","b");
```

which gives error:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::catfile called
```

I know I could use  `use File::Spec::Functions`, but that would import all functions from `File::Spec`, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw{ catfile };
```

The reason why it doesn't work for `File::Spec` is the module is object oriented. All the functions are in fact class methods.